# Sort by date for an array of objects with each object containing arrays of dates

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array of countries with offices opened, how do I sort the array in order from the earliest date recorded to the latest date recorded?
The original array is

```
countriesList = [
 { country: 'USA',
 officeOpened: [ {date: '2016-04-01', city: 'Denver'}],
 officeClosed: [ {date: '2016-10-01', city: 'NY'}]
 },
 { country: 'UK',
 officeOpened: [{date: '2023-05-01', city: 'London'}],
 officeClosed: []
 },
 { country: 'China',
 officeOpened: [{date: '2015-01-01', city: 'Shanghai'}],
 officeClosed: []
 },
 { country: 'No-office',
 officeOpened: [],
 officeClosed: []
 },
 { country: 'Many-offices',
 officeOpened: [{date: '2023-04-01', city: 'A'} , {date: '2023-06-01', city: 'B'}],
 officeClosed: []
 }
]
```

Expected output:

```
countriesList = [
 { country: 'China',
 officeOpened: [{date: '2015-01-01', city: 'Shanghai'}]
 },
 { country: 'USA',
 officeOpened: [ {date: '2016-04-01', city: 'Denver'}],
 officeClosed: [ {date: '2016-10-01', city: 'NY'}]
 },
 { country: 'Many-offices',
 officeOpened: [{date: '2023-04-01', city: 'A'} , {date: '2023-06-01', city: 'B'}],
 officeOpened: []
 },
 { country: 'UK',
 officeOpened: [{date: '2023-05-01', city: 'London'}]
 },
  { country: 'No-office',
 officeOpened: [],
 officeOpened: []
 }
]
```

So I want to sort the country object in this array. Notice how the earliest date record was in China, so the whole China object is sorted to the first place, then comes the second earliest date recorded in the USA, the UK. How do I do this?
I've seen some similar question, but not exactly with this type of data structure.

Edit: if it's relevant, officeOpened/Closed can also be empty, in which case, it can either be first or last in the array. And as one of the answer points out, we only need to care about and sort base on the first office opened in a country (the first object in officeOpened/Closed array because these arrays are sorted beforehand.)

Comment: Can there be more than one element in the `officeOpened` or `officeClosed` arrays? Do you want to sort only by the dates in `officeOpened` or do you also want to consider the `officeClosed` dates?

Comment: @derpirscher There can be more elements in `Opened` and `Closed` or no element at all. I want to sort by all dates available in every array, so consider both `officeClosed` and `officeOpened`. And later if the system introduces new array with dates, such as `officeInConstruct` (with the same prop 'date' and 'city') then the dates in this newly introduced array should also be considered.

Comment: Do you have a question? ("I want to sort" doesn't count).

Comment: My short question is how to sort it. I omitted some bigger picture but the data structure is actually more than just `officeClosed`, `officeOpened`, but with `officeStartedHiring` stuff like that. And I am just confused on how to sort everything based on *every date* recorded, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the date and sort by string.

```js
const
    countriesList = [{ country: 'USA', officeOpened: [{ date: '2016-04-01', city: 'Denver' }], officeClosed: [{ date: '2016-10-01', city: 'NY' }] }, { country: 'UK', officeOpened: [{ date: '2023-05-01', city: 'London' }] }, { country: 'China', officeOpened: [{ date: '2015-01-01', city: 'Shanghai' }] }];
    
countriesList.sort(({ officeOpened: [a] }, { officeOpened: [b] }) =>
    a.date.localeCompare(b.date)
);

console.log(countriesList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that 1. officeOpened will always be before officeClosed, and 2. each officeOpened will always have an element in the array, and 3. There will only be one element in the officeOpened array or we only care about the first element, then we can do:

```js
countriesList = [
 { country: 'USA',
 officeOpened: [ {date: '2016-04-01', city: 'Denver'}],
 officeClosed: [ {date: '2016-10-01', city: 'NY'}]
 },
 { country: 'UK',
 officeOpened: [{date: '2023-05-01', city: 'London'}]
 },
 { country: 'China',
 officeOpened: [{date: '2015-01-01', city: 'Shanghai'}]
 }
]

countriesList.sort((a, b) => a.officeOpened[0].date.localeCompare(b.officeOpened[0].date));

console.log(countriesList);
```

Answer (score 0):

As `officeOpened` is an array, I assume this array can have multiple entries for each country. If yes, the following searches the earliest date for each countries and then sorts by this date.

```js
var countriesList = [
  { 
    country: 'USA',
    officeOpened: [ {date: '2016-04-01', city: 'Denver'}],
    officeClosed: [ {date: '2016-10-01', city: 'NY'}]
  },
  { 
    country: 'UK',
    officeOpened: [{date: '2023-05-01', city: 'London'}],
    officeClosed: []
  },
  { 
    country: 'China',
    officeOpened: [{date: '2015-01-01', city: 'Shanghai'}],
    officeClosed: []
  },
  { 
    country: 'No-office',
    officeOpened: [],
    officeOpened: []
  },
  { 
    country: 'Many-offices',
    officeOpened: [{date: '2023-04-01', city: 'A'} , {date: '2023-06-01', city: 'B'}],
    officeClosed: []
  }
]

function earliestDate(country) {
  let earliest = "9999";
  for (let a of Object.values(country)) {
    if (!Array.isArray(a)) continue; 
    for (let x of a) {
      if (x?.date && x.date < earliest)
        earliest = x.date;
    }
  }

  return earliest;
}


var sorted = countriesList.slice().sort((a,b) => earliestDate(a).localeCompare(earliestDate(b)));

console.log(sorted)
```

The `earliestDate` function searches for the earliest date in all array-shaped properties of the `country`.

1. check every property of the `country` object if it is an array and if yes
2. check if any of the elements in that array has a `date` property and if yes
3. check if that `date` is less than the current earliest date

If no date is to be found exists, "9999" is returned, so that country is moved to the end of the list.

Of course you can also do this with some fancy "oneliner" with `Array.reduce` and `Array.map`. But for explaining the concept I find plain old `for .. of` loops simpler to read.

Of course this implementation is not the fastest one, as it recalculates the `earliestDate` in every comparison of the sort.
A better implementation would call `earliestDate` once for every element in the array and reuse this value. But I leave that as exercise ...

Comment: You know you don't have to sort n array to find minimum value.

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, I know, and that's also the reason why I mentioned that this implemention isn't the fastest. It should only give the idea on how to sort this data structure (and this way it was the fastest to write runable code)

Comment: Does it make any different if the type of date is 'Date'. TS will throws an error 'Property 'localeCompare' does not exist on type 'Date'.'? - I think this is a typescript/Angular problem since testing on js online compiler yiels no error.

Comment: Of course it makes a difference if the `date` property  is a `string` (like in your example) or a `Date`. But that's not a TS problem. TS will just help you to notice your problem earlier. If your data really contains `Date`s it will throw runtime errors if you use `localeCompare`

Answer (score 0):

1. Сreate an array with country and its earliest date (use `Array::reduce()` to find the date)
2. Sort it by the date
3. Map back to countries

```js
const sorted = countriesList
  .map(c => [c.officeOpened.reduce((r, {date:d}) => d < r ? d : r, '3'), c])
  .sort(([a],[b]) => a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0).map(e => e[1]);

sorted.map(c => console.log(JSON.stringify(c)))
```

```html
<script>
var countriesList=[{country:"USA",officeOpened:[{date:"2016-04-01",city:"Denver"}],officeClosed:[{date:"2016-10-01",city:"NY"}]},{country:"UK",officeOpened:[{date:"2023-05-01",city:"London"}],officeClosed:[]},{country:"China",officeOpened:[{date:"2015-01-01",city:"Shanghai"}],officeClosed:[]},{country:"No-office",officeOpened:[],officeOpened:[]},{country:"Many-offices",officeOpened:[{date:"2023-04-01",city:"A"},{date:"2023-06-01",city:"B"}],officeClosed:[]}];
</script>
```

```
` Chrome/119
---------------------------------------------------------
Alexander     1.00x  |  x1000000  192  194  197  200  212
derpirscher   6.51x  |   x100000  125  127  131  134  141
---------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
var countriesList=[{country:"USA",officeOpened:[{date:"2016-04-01",city:"Denver"}],officeClosed:[{date:"2016-10-01",city:"NY"}]},{country:"UK",officeOpened:[{date:"2023-05-01",city:"London"}],officeClosed:[]},{country:"China",officeOpened:[{date:"2015-01-01",city:"Shanghai"}],officeClosed:[]},{country:"No-office",officeOpened:[],officeOpened:[]},{country:"Many-offices",officeOpened:[{date:"2023-04-01",city:"A"},{date:"2023-06-01",city:"B"}],officeClosed:[]}];

// @benchmark derpirscher
  
function earliestDate(country) {
  let props = ["officeOpened", "officeClosed"];
  let earliest = props
    .map(p => country[p]?.map(x => x.date).sort()[0])  //find the minium date in each of the arrays
    .filter(x  => !!x)  //filter out empty values (in case an array is empty or does not exist at all)
    .sort()[0];  //find the minimum of the remaining values
  return earliest ?? "9999"
}

countriesList.slice().sort((a,b) => earliestDate(a).localeCompare(earliestDate(b)));

// @benchmark Alexander
countriesList
  .map(c => [c.officeOpened.reduce((r, {date:d}) => d < r ? d : r, '3'), c])
  .sort(([a],[b]) => a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0).map(e => e[1]);

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const countriesList = [
 { country: 'USA',
 officeOpened: [ {date: '2016-04-01', city: 'Denver'}],
 officeClosed: [ {date: '2016-10-01', city: 'NY'}]
 },
 { country: 'UK',
 officeOpened: [{date: '2023-05-01', city: 'London'}],
 officeClosed: []
 },
 { country: 'China',
 officeOpened: [{date: '2015-01-01', city: 'Shanghai'}],
 officeClosed: []
 },
 { country: 'No-office',
 officeOpened: [],
 officeClosed: []
 },
 { country: 'Many-offices',
 officeOpened: [{date: '2023-04-01', city: 'A'} , {date: '2023-06-01', city: 'B'}],
 officeClosed: []
 }
]

function sortByEarliestOfficeOpened(countriesList) {
  return countriesList.sort((a, b) => {
    // If either country has no office opened, move it to the end
    if (a.officeOpened.length === 0 && b.officeOpened.length === 0) return 0;
    if (a.officeOpened.length === 0) return 1;
    if (b.officeOpened.length === 0) return -1;

    // Extract the earliest officeOpened date for each country
    const earliestDateA = new Date(Math.min(...a.officeOpened.map((office) => new Date(office.date))));
    const earliestDateB = new Date(Math.min(...b.officeOpened.map((office) => new Date(office.date))));

    // Compare the dates
    return earliestDateA - earliestDateB;
  });
}

const sortedCountriesList = sortByEarliestOfficeOpened(countriesList);
console.log(sortedCountriesList);
```